# Get Current Status based on Total Count

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, database-connection, relational-database

I have problem to making a condition (if then else) on mysql query.

Briefly, i have 3 tables that relate each other.

```
m_shift_schedule    site_shift_schedule      m_ticket
================    ===================     ============
* shift_id   ======> * shift_id             * ticket_id
* start_time         * shift_date           * ticket_status
* end_time           * user_id   ========>  * ticket_served_by
```

My query right now :

```
SELECT user_id
FROM site_shift_schedule
LEFT JOIN m_shift_schedule ON site_shift_schedule.shift_id = m_shift_schedule.shift_id
WHERE site_shift_schedule.shift_date =  '2019-02-11';
```

[image]

What should i do, if i want to make the ouput become like this?

Idle = m_ticket.ticket_status(4 or 5 or 6) and tot count m_ticket.ticket_served_by < 2

Busy = m_ticket.ticket_status(4 or 5 or 6) and tot count m_ticket.ticket_served_by = 2

Overload = m_ticket.ticket_status(4 or 5 or 6) and tot count m_ticket.ticket_served_by > 2

```
      user_id                           Status
  =============================       ============
 ismail.rahman.saanin@random.co          Idle
 lutfi.aldi.nugroho@random.co            Busy
```

Help me guys, thanks . . .

Comment: Use a [CASE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) function in your `SELECT user_id, CASE ... END CASE as Status, .... FROM ....`

Comment: i dont get it man @danblack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `CASE WHEN Expression` and `Group By`

```
SELECT user_id,
case when count(m_ticket.ticket_served_by)<2 then 'idle' 
     when count(m_ticket.ticket_served_by)=2 then 'Busy' 
     when count(m_ticket.ticket_served_by)>2 then 'Overload' end as status
FROM site_shift_schedule
LEFT JOIN m_shift_schedule ON site_shift_schedule.shift_id = m_shift_schedule.shift_id
left join m_ticket on site_shift_schedule.user_id=m_ticket.ticket_served_by
WHERE site_shift_schedule.shift_date =  '2019-02-11' and m_ticket.ticket_status in (4,5,6)
group by user_id
```